# Eclipse OverviewRuler not showing annotations

Tags: eclipse

I created a SourceViewer as described in this link https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Text

I could not get the annotation indications on the right side of the editor.

I am trying out this in a view instead of an editor.

I tried calling `overViewRuler.addAnnotationType("My annotation type");` and also called the `overViewRuler.update();` Nothing seems to work. Is there any way to show the marks on the right side overview ruler of a source viewer in a view?

Comment: I think that code probably expects you to have defined the annotation with the `org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes` and `org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification` extension points.

Comment: You added the annotation type, but did you add any annotations?

Comment: Yes I added annotations too :) I thought those extension points are needed  only if I use markers. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Thanks for your support greg-449 and nitind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.

The problem was

> overviewRulerPreferenceValue="true"

was missing in the plugin.xml. I am giving the complete code below in case any one wants to try.

```
        package sourceviewsample;

    import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.Document;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.Position;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.Annotation;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.AnnotationModel;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.CompositeRuler;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.IAnnotationAccess;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.IOverviewRuler;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.ISharedTextColors;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.LineNumberRulerColumn;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.OverviewRuler;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer;
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewerConfiguration;
    import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
    import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.RGB;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
    import org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.text.EditorsPlugin;
    import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;
    import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AnnotationPreference;
    import org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.SourceViewerDecorationSupport;

    /**
     * An example of using a SourceViewer with Annotation support outside of the
     * TextEditor class. This annotations can be configured in the preferences if
     * the markerAnnotationSpecification is setup in the plugin.xml.
     * 
     * To execute this, run as an Eclipse Application and then open a file using
     * Open with.. -> Other, and select Sample Editor. You will see the text that
     * comes in this example and the highlight.
     */
    public class SampleEditor extends ViewPart
    {
        public static final String              ANNO_TYPE          = "com.mycompany.element";
        public static final String              ANNO_KEY_HIGHLIGHT = "annotateElemHighlight";
        public static final String              ANNO_KEY_OVERVIEW  = "annotateElemOverviewRuler";
        public static final String              ANNO_KEY_VERTICAL  = "annotateElemVertialRuler";
        public static final String              ANNO_KEY_TEXT      = "annotateElemText";
        public static final String              ANNO_KEY_COLOR     = "annotateElemColor";

        protected SourceViewer                  _sourceViewer;
        protected SourceViewerDecorationSupport _sds;
        protected IDocument                     _document;
        protected AnnotationModel               _annotationModel;

        protected String                        _docString         = "this\nis\na\ntest\ndocument";

        public SampleEditor()
        {
            super();
        }

        public void createPartControl(Composite parent)
        {
            int VERTICAL_RULER_WIDTH = 12;

            int styles = SWT.V_SCROLL
                | SWT.H_SCROLL
                | SWT.MULTI
                | SWT.BORDER
                | SWT.FULL_SELECTION;
            ISharedTextColors sharedColors = EditorsPlugin.getDefault()
                    .getSharedTextColors();


            IAnnotationAccess iaccess = new IAnnotationAccess() {

                @Override
                public boolean isTemporary(Annotation annotation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isMultiLine(Annotation annotation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public Object getType(Annotation annotation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return ANNO_TYPE;
                }
            };


            IOverviewRuler overviewRuler = new OverviewRuler(iaccess,
                                                             VERTICAL_RULER_WIDTH,
                                                             sharedColors);
            CompositeRuler ruler = new CompositeRuler(VERTICAL_RULER_WIDTH);

            _document = new Document();
            _document.set(_docString);

            _annotationModel = new AnnotationModel();
            _annotationModel.connect(_document);

            _sourceViewer = new SourceViewer(parent,
                                             ruler,
                                             overviewRuler,
                                             true,
                                             styles);
            _sourceViewer.configure(new SourceViewerConfiguration());

            _sds = new SourceViewerDecorationSupport(_sourceViewer,
                                                     overviewRuler,
                                                     null,
                                                     sharedColors);

            AnnotationPreference ap = new AnnotationPreference();
            ap.setColorPreferenceKey(ANNO_KEY_COLOR);
            ap.setColorPreferenceValue(new RGB(150, 200, 250));
            ap.setHighlightPreferenceKey(ANNO_KEY_HIGHLIGHT);
            ap.setVerticalRulerPreferenceKey(ANNO_KEY_VERTICAL);
            ap.setOverviewRulerPreferenceKey(ANNO_KEY_OVERVIEW);
            ap.setOverviewRulerPreferenceValue(true);
            ap.setTextPreferenceKey(ANNO_KEY_TEXT);
            ap.setAnnotationType(ANNO_TYPE);
            _sds.setAnnotationPreference(ap);

            _sds.install(EditorsPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());

            _sourceViewer.setDocument(_document, _annotationModel);

            _sourceViewer.getControl().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,
                                                                  SWT.FILL,
                                                                  true,
                                                                  true));

            ruler.addDecorator(0, new LineNumberRulerColumn());

            overviewRuler.addAnnotationType(ANNO_TYPE);

            overviewRuler.getControl().setBackground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));

            Annotation annotation = new Annotation(false);
            annotation.setType(ANNO_TYPE);
            Position position = new Position(0, 4);
            _annotationModel.addAnnotation(annotation, position);
            try {
                _document.addPosition(position);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            overviewRuler.setModel(_annotationModel);
        }

        public void dispose()
        {
            // The _sourceViewer goes away automatically when the editor goes
            // away because it's hooked to the controls
            _sds.dispose();
        }

        //
        // This stuff below is just needed to make the EditorPart happy
        // 

        public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor)
        {
        }

        public void doSaveAs()
        {
        }

    //    public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input)
    //        throws PartInitException
    //    {
    //        setSite(site);
    //        setInput(input);
    //    }
    //
    //    public boolean isDirty()
    //    {
    //        return false;
    //    }

        public boolean isSaveAsAllowed()
        {
            return false;
        }

        public void setFocus()
        {

        }

    }
```

Here is the plugin.xml as well

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.2"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes">
      <type
            markerSeverity="0"
            name="com.mycompany.element">
      </type>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification">
      <specification
            annotationType="com.mycompany.element"
            colorPreferenceKey="annotateElemColor"
            colorPreferenceValue="255,255,0"
            highlightPreferenceKey="annotateElemHighlight"
            highlightPreferenceValue="true"
            includeOnPreferencePage="true"
            label="Sample Annotation"
            overviewRulerPreferenceKey="annotateElemOverviewRuler"
            overviewRulerPreferenceValue="true"
            textPreferenceKey="annotateElemText"
            verticalRulerPreferenceKey="annotateElemVerticalRuler"
            verticalRulerPreferenceValue="true">
      </specification>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
         <view id="sourceviewsample.SampleEditor" 
         name="Source Viewer"
         class="sourceviewsample.SampleEditor"/>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```